# How to set up a 12 x 12 matrix using clpfd library

Tags: matrix, prolog, clpfd

I am new to constraint logic programming and wanted to know, how I can use clpfd to set up a 12 x 12 matrix in prolog. I am using the swi prolog ide.

Comment: Is this Prolog, or ECLiPSe?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem it is prolog I am using swi prolog not ECLiPSe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To allocate a matrix of variables, we can do in plain Prolog:

```
matrix(N,Rows) :- bagof(R,Y^(between(1,N,Y),length(R,N)),Rows).
```

Then, to constraint each 'cell' to take values from a domain (let say 1..3), using library(yall):

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).
?- matrix(12, Mat), maplist([R]>>(R ins 1..3), Mat).
```

or, with builtins:

```
?- matrix(12, Mat), bagof(t, R^(member(R, Mat), R ins 1..3), _).
```